# Handling rows with 2 lines of data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

My DataFrame looks like this :
[image]
there are some rows ( example: 297) where the "Price" column has two values ( Plugs and Quarts), I have filled the Nans with the previous row since it belongs to the same Latin Name. However I was thinking of splitting the Price Column further into two columns with Names "Quarts" and "Plugs" and fill the amount, 0 if there are no Plugs found and the same with Quarts.

Example :

```
Plugs | Quarts
0 | 2
2 | 3
4 | 0
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: what if the price column don't have plugs / quarts ? For eg. row 295

Comment: When i checked, that row is the only row which has that value and I have decided to drop it since it won't do any good to my EDA.